# Create a shortcut to a bookmark folder in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, bookmarks

As with shortcuts in Windows Explorer or aliases in Mac OS Finder, I want to create shortcuts to a bookmark folder in Google Chrome.

For example :
I have a folder "Shenmue" in my bookmarks, I want to put this folder in three different bookmark folders at the same time : "videogames", "art" and "favorites".

Answer (score 4):

Here are the instructions:

1. Move your bookmark folder to the "Bookmarks Bar".
2. Close any existing "Bookmark Manager" tabs.
3. Right click the bookmark folder (`Shenmue` in your case) on the "Bookmarks Bar", select "Bookmark Manager" (as shown in the following screenshot):

   [image: Get the URL of the bookmark folder - Step 1/2]
4. Now, you have a link to your bookmark folder, which looks like `chrome://bookmarks/#2245` (as shown in the following screenshot):

   [image: Get the URL of the bookmark folder - Step 2/2]
5. Click the star on the right of the address bar, and select the folder you want to put it into (`videogames` in your case). Note: by default, the newly created bookmark of the link to `Shenmue` will be named `Bookmark Manager`.
6. Rename the newly created bookmark (in `videogames`) from the default `Bookmark Manager` to `Shenmue`.
7. Copy-and-paste the newly created and renamed bookmark `Shenmue` to your folders `art` and `favorites`.
8. Reverse step 1 of these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the URL - in alert box. Then create new bookmark and paste what you copied from alert.

Add this as a bookmarklet (create new bookmark and copy this as the link)
`javascript:alert('chrome://bookmarks/#'+bmm.list.parentId)`

Then, open bookmark manager, click on the folder you want and click the bookmarklet. Alert will have the text for the folder URL.

You could also just run it from the address bar, but Chrome eliminates "javascript:" when pasting so you'll need to paste something like this
`.javascript:alert('chrome://bookmarks/#'+bmm.list.parentId)`

and then go back and remove that leading dot.